# Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/* for module i915

Tags: debian, initramfs, firmware

I am getting these warnings every time I update my `initramfs` image(-s) with [`update-initramfs`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.8.en.html) on my Dell PowerEdge T20 server running [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#Copyright,_trademark,_and_naming) [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) [Buster](https://www.debian.org/News/2019/20190706) 10.*0*. Is there a fix?

---

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cnl_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_dmc_ver1_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_39.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver9_29.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver9_33.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_ver02_00_1810.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_ver01_07_1398.bin for module i915
```

Comment: Those messages are generated as `update-initramfs` looks at the `modinfo <module>` output to identify the firmware requirements of each module it's including. Normally, the appropriate firmware package like `firmware-linux`will fix them; but if using a backported or custom kernel, you might need a newer version of some firmware than is available in the distribution's firmware packages. If that's the case, go to the [linux-firmware Git repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/) and find the version you need in there.

Comment: The GPU drivers like `i915` or `nouveau` support many versions of the respective GPUs, and so they have no choice but to list in their `modinfo` data the firmware files for every possible chip version they support that needs firmware. But you actually only need just the firmware versions that correspond to the hardware your system has.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

For a general solution, `apt-file` is your way to solve the `Possible missing firmware...` warning. E.g.:

```
apt-file search bxt_dmc

firmware-misc-nonfree: /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1.bin
firmware-misc-nonfree: /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
```

Showing that the package `firmware-misc-nonfree` provides the missing firmware.

Installing the `firmware-linux` package [solves the problem](/a/556947/153195) because `firmware-linux` depends on `firmware-linux-nonfree` which depends on `firmware-misc-nonfree`.

---

Detailed instructions:

For Debian 10, add `non-free` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free 
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

For Debian 12, add `non-free-firmware` to your [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) as [instructed](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.html#non-free-split):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
```

> **Note:** the `non-free` repo is irrelevant for such packages, keep it if it's already there.

Install `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Debian: [apt-file](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file)

Comment: Thank you for teaching people to fish rather than giving them fishsticks.

Comment: You can also use `dpkg-search -S i915/bx_dmc` to locate them, if you already have that installed.

Comment: Another way to "Add non-free to your /etc/apt/sources.list" - use: `sudo apt edit-sources`

Comment: do you have to worry about it if your model is not included in the list of the missing?

Comment: @Scott Please ask a new question, because this appears not to belong here directly.

Comment: @VlastimilBurián how so? I get the messages on my system, but the errors in the message all refer to firmware for devices that don't match the one I have in my machine. Do I need to worry about these messages or not?

Comment: @ankostis  Thank you for the edit. I have included Debian 10 again because the question is initially about Debian Buster.

Answer (score 32):

You may download them from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915) and copy downloaded files to `/lib/firmware/i915/`, then `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

(then `sudo apt-get update -y`)

Comment: It is probably better to install the proper package, as some other sollutions have pointed out.  Best is to actually search for the package that owns the files.  That can be done with `apt-file search` or `dpkg-search -S` and add part of the filename, like `i915/bxc_dcm` which is mentioned in the logs.

Comment: @Anders , probably yes but I myself have the `linux-firware` installed and the file I need `adlp_dmc.bin` is nowhere to be found on my system.

I had to download the file manually as @Dr.Eissa suggested to fix my issue. Thanks @Dr.Eissa!

Answer (score 31):

It appears the answer was the whole time in front of my eyes.

I have finally found the right package: [`firmware-linux`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-linux), which installs most of the missing firmware. Install it with:

**Debian** and derivatives:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-linux
```

---

**Ubuntu** and derivatives:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

---

Those warnings might be gone afterward. And if not, there is AFAIK no package to solve it, therefore you may have to download and install separate firmware files as in the other answer.

---

On my machine with Linux Mint 21, these files when unpacked, take up around 1GB of disk space, so it is a huge package, be aware of that:

```
$ du -sh /lib/firmware/
921M    /lib/firmware/
```

Comment: And a more general solution is to use `apt-file search` or `dpkg-search -S` to locate those packages that own those firmware files.

Comment: @Anders This requires having `apt-file` installed and prepared/updated.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Like `apt install apt-file`.   Stil, `dpkg-search -S` I believe doesn't need that.

Comment: For anyone using Ubuntu, installing `linux-firmware` but still having the same warnings of missing firmware, this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1481205/1579334) helped me solving it.

Answer (score 0):

all you need firmwares is easy to download directly from
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/refs/

Comment: You do not say what happens after kernel update/upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Your Mileage Might Vary, but I was getting these "`missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/...file`" messages after an update. 
My system didn't even have a `/lib/firmware/i915` directory. 
And all operations seemed normal.

Throwing caution to the winds and having a recent full backup,
I decided I'd try creating bogus null files
that the `update-initramfs` process was complaining about. 
I copied its error messages to a temporary file (e.g., `mytempfile`)
and using one of my text editors (think vi, mcedit, sed, etc.)
changed the lines from e.g.

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin for module i915
```

to

```
sudo touch /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
```

for each erroring `.bin` file.

I then created the necessary directory:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/i915
```

And sourced my tempory file: `source mytempfile`

And generated a new intramfs: `sudo update-initramfs -u`

And observed no more error messages about missing `i915` `.bin` files.

A test reboot and everything came up OK.

Some words of caution:

1. Have a backup.
2. Only do this once you have fully updated your system
3. Verify you don't have any problems which may interfere.
4. This worked for me.  YMMV.  And this workaround is probably not 'approved' by the poobahs.