# Debian, missing a lot of different firmware

Tags: debian, apt, firmware

I get the following warnings whenever I run `apt upgrade`:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_dmc_ver1_09.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_04.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_huc_2.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_huc_4.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_33.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_huc_9.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_33.0.4.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_35.2.0.bin for module i915
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/\* for module i915](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556946/possible-missing-firmware-lib-firmware-i915-for-module-i915)

Comment: @PhilipCouling I tried it, But it either gives me no answer, or a package that is already installed.

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: @jsotola how to fix this. What packages should I install? what firmware could I be missing? etc. or, if it isn't a problem, should I be bothered by it at all?

Comment: ok, then edit your post and include the questions please ... they do not belong in comments

Comment: If your devide works, just ignore it.  If it doesn't work, add `nonfree` to your repository and search for the package that own any of those files, like `apt-file search i915/icl_dmc` or `dpkg-search -D i915/icl_dmc`.  And if any package own that file, you can install it with `apt` and reboot the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

1. change to `root` (either via `su` or `sudo su`, depending on your distribution's configuration)
2. install `git`

   ```
   apt install git
   ```
3. retrieve the firmware

   ```
   cd /tmp
   git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
   ```
4. "import" the `i915` firmware

   ```
   cd linux-firmware/
   cp i915/* /lib/firmware/i915/
   ```
5. update the initramfs

   ```
   update-initramfs -u
   ```

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Or better yet, search for the package that contain the firmware.  It isn't that hard.  Then you don't need to download it at al.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a driver starts supporting additional hardware that the system does not have firmware for yet, or hardware for which the firmware cannot be legally distributed (e.g., chips that appear only in Apple hardware).  Additionally, there's also hardware where the firmware enables some performance improvement (e.g., TCP segment offloading for network cards) but the chip works fine without it.

Since this is your graphics card, if your graphics are fine and you have OpenGL (3D) support working, then there's nothing to do.  If your card isn't performing well, you can find the relevant firmware package and install it.  If it's already installed, then there's nothing you need to do.  Debian will package the firmware for additional cards in due time, and the warning is harmless: it's just there to tell you that you may want to install the firmware if it's available.

Comment: sadly my graphics card isn't working well. I have had a few crashes.

Comment: Just use `apt-file search i915/icl_dmc` or `dpkg-search -S i915/icl_dmc` and it will tell you which package you need to install for loading the firmware.  That is a general answer, by the way.  You can search for any file for which package own them.   Works on Debian and any distribution derived from Debian.