# GUI won't open on newly installed debian

Tags: debian, gui

I installed debian without problems. I chose xfce as GUI. And i have internet connection. I restarted when the installation was complete. But the login screen does not appear. Screen is completely black. There is only one flashing dash. I looked for errors using this command:

```
less /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

And i got the below errors:

```
EE open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory

EE unable to find a valid framebuffer device

EE Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section

EE Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices.
```

What should i do, can you help me?

I have Intel uhd graphics

**Edit1:**
I downloaded xserver-org-core and reinstalled debian. but nothing has changed.

**EDIT2:**
I downloaded debian from [here](https://www.debian.org/download). I also downloaded the firmware from [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/buster/10.10.0/).

I copied these files from the firmware.zip file to the firmware folder inside the usb.

Files:

```
firmware-intel-sound_20190114-2_all.deb
firmware-intelwimax_20190114-2_all.deb
firmware-iwlwifi_20190114-2_all.deb
firmware-linux-free_3.4_all.deb
firmware-misc-nonfree_20190114-2_all.deb
firmware-realtek_20190114-2_all.deb
intel-microcode_3.20210216.1~deb10u1_amd64.deb
```

In addition to these, I added the file I downloaded from [this site](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/xserver-xorg-core/download).

CPU = intel i3 1005g1

GPU = intel uhd graphics 10th generation

**EDIT3:**
I added "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main" to /etc/apt/sources.list, what should I do next?  I ran sudo apt-get update and rebooted but still nothing changed.

**EDIT4:**
What else should I download besides the above firmware?

**EDIT5:**

sources.list contents

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bustermain non-free contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bustermain non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free


deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EE open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

This indicates the kernel `i915` framebuffer display driver has not been activated, perhaps because the necessary firmware is missing. It looks like the Intel iGPU firmware files are in package `firmware-misc-nonfree`.

If you did not enable access to Debian's "non-free" repository on installation, you'll need to do that first before you can install the `firmware-misc-nonfree` package.

For more details, [see this question and its answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/556946/258991).

Also, if you chose Debian 10 ("buster"), its default kernel might be too old for the newest Intel UHD Graphics iGPUs. But [Debian 11 is scheduled to be released during this week](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2021/07/msg00003.html), so you might want to install it in the expectation that it will very soon become the new stable version.

Comment: i already downloaded firmware-misc-nonfree.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia's list of Intel iGPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology), all the processors with the **UHD** Graphics are so new that you might have to check the `dmesg` output to see which firmware files you require, and fetch the necessary firmware files yourself from tthe [linux-firmware repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/i915). Depending on the exact CPU model, you might even need a newer kernel than Debian 10 has.

Comment: "If you did not enable access to Debian's "non-free" repository on installation, you'll need to do that first before you can install the firmware-misc-nonfree package." How can I do that? And I will do a more detailed edit above. Thanks for your answer

Comment: What you wrote is very precious to me, but since I am new to this universe, I do not understand anything.  I also made a more detailed edit above @telcoM

Comment: Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` line you added so that it will say `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster main non-free`. Then run `sudo apt-get update` again and now packages like `firmware-misc-nonfree` should be installable with just `sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree`.

Comment: I did what you said but the situation is still the same. I couldn't understand why the problem was caused. @telcoM

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work. Errors that prevent the graphical interface from working are necessarily hiding somewhere. How can i reach them? I've been trying to install debian for 5 days. Can you help? All i want is to be a linux user?? @telcoM

Comment: Your CPU is newer than the release date of Debian 10, and so the kernel's `i915` kernel module version may be too old to support the iGPU in that CPU. I recommend installing Debian 11 instead, as installing a newer kernel from a [Debian backports repository](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) is a fairly tricky for a new user. Debian 11 will be the new stable release of Debian after 2021-08-14. But if you want to see the errors, run `dmesg` as root to view the kernel's message buffer. If there are no messages mentioning `i915` at all, then the kernel is too old.

Comment: I downloaded debian 11 yesterday. I did not encounter any problems. Thank you @telcoM