# Missing Firmware

Tags: firmware, zorin

On my Zorin OS 15.3 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) base,

I get the Missing Firmware error on my computer and i have searched for some answers and i found this solution is that you are going to use apt-file and after that i installed that i got this below:

apt-file search bxt_dmc

linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1.bin
linux-firmware: /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin

My question is that how do i install these firm-wares on the computer?
I have tried with sudo apt-get install but i get these errors below?

sudo apt-get install /lib/firmware/i915
Läser paketlistor… Finished
E: Unsupported file /lib/firmware/i915 given on commandline

Comment: I have already checked that?

Comment: What is your Linux distro?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Zorin OS is a fork of Ubuntu?

Comment: For Ubuntu the correct package name is `linux-firmware`.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Is this the right command sudo apt-get install linux-firmware?

Comment: yes it is go ahead `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`

Comment: Let's continue discuss that in the chat @LinuxSecurityFreak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128376/discussion-between-jonte-yh-and-linuxsecurityfreak).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/\* for module i915](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556946/possible-missing-firmware-lib-firmware-i915-for-module-i915)

Comment: I have already looked at that :(