# kernel panic after after parrotOS upgrade

Tags: linux, kernel, configuration, dpkg

after attempting `sudo apt upgrade` on a fresh install of parrot os, new kernel update is present but trying to boot into it from grub gives gives me a kernel panic.

here is what i tried and with what errors ive been getting:

```
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  apache2 linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 linux-headers-amd64 
  linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 linux-image-amd64 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (6.5.13-1parrot1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build........(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
 linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (= 6.5.13-1parrot1); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (6.5.13-1parrot1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64.
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build.........(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up apache2 (2.4.57-2) ...
info: Switch to mpm prefork for package libapache2-mod-php8.2: No action required
info: Executing deferred 'a2enmod php8.2' for package libapache2-mod-php8.2
Can't locate if.pm in @INC (you may need to install the if module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.36.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.36.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.36 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.36 /usr/share/perl/5.36 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 15.
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (= 6.5.13-1parrot1); however:
  Package linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
 linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64
 apache2
 linux-image-amd64
Scanning application launchers
Removing duplicate launchers or broken launchers
Launchers are updated
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (6.5.13-1parrot1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64.
/usr/sbin/dkms: line 2497: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build.........(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
Failed to process /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64.postinst line 11.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-amd64:
 linux-headers-amd64 depends on linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (= 6.5.13-1parrot1); however:
  Package linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (6.5.13-1parrot1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64.
/usr/sbin/dkms: line 2497: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Sign command: /lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 KSRC=/lib/modules/6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64/build........(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/realtek-rtl8188eus/5.3.9~git20230101.f8ead57/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
dkms: autoinstall for kernel: 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 failed!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up apache2 (2.4.57-2) ...
info: Switch to mpm prefork for package libapache2-mod-php8.2: No action required
info: Executing deferred 'a2enmod php8.2' for package libapache2-mod-php8.2
Can't locate if.pm in @INC (you may need to install the if module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.36.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.36.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.36 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.36 /usr/share/perl/5.36 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/a2enmod line 15.
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
 linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 (= 6.5.13-1parrot1); however:
  Package linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
 linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64
 apache2
 linux-image-amd64
```

im sure the error lies in the last lines:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-headers-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64
linux-headers-amd64
linux-image-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64
apache2
linux-image-amd64
```

i dont know what to do from here, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` & `sudo apt --fix-broken install` all result in the same issue, might be a configuration problem.

if you need any extra information let me know and thanks for your time

Comment: My guess: the failed external dkms modules build prevents the initramfs file to be created. You could try manually: `update-initramfs -c -k 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64` (or replace -c with -u if it complains). This won't give you your expected network.

Comment: Welcome. As said @A.B the dkms built of `rtl8188eus` is blocked. Try to boot the previous kernel, remove dkms. Upgrade your system, then reinstall `dkms`. Rebuild the wifi driver manually. I can't answer because there are many failures in the system upgrade.

Comment: Posted on behalf of @JohnMuraguri : "Experiencing the same issue too a few minutes after upgrading my Parrot OS. apt -f install hasn't fixed it. Waiting for the result of dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: thank you @A.B and @GAD3R for you suggestions, i purged ```dkms``` and rebuilt the wifi driver, now after trying again, the output after ```apt upgrade``` is ```Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
```
i tried ```sudo apt-get purge apache2*``` and ```apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-configured `linux-image` and `linux-headers` are solved by:

- Booting the previous kernel
- Removing `dkms`
- Upgrading the kernel
- Reinstalling `dkms`
- Building the `rtl8188eus`

To solve the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
```

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/apache2 /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq apache2
```

To solve :

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/*
```

[Here is a detailed answer on U&L.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556946/possible-missing-firmware-lib-firmware-i915-for-module-i915/557015#557015)

Comment: perfect fixed all the problems, only problem im facing is with ```update-initramfs -c -k 6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64``` which leaves me with ```update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-13parrot1-amd64
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_huc_gsc.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/mtl_guc_70.bin for module i915```
any suggestions?

Comment: @xoity Answer edited to solve the last problem.